# xslt - Stripping blank spaces in the values of tags

Tags: xml, xslt

This is my xml file-

```
<update-all-attributes>
   <document name="http:blah">
      <price>115.00 USD</price>
       <brand_qty>10 A</brand_qty>
       <style_size>10 A_new in stock</style_size>
   </document>
</update-all-attributes>
```

How will I strip blank spaces in the values of  and  so that my xml after modifying with xslt 1.0 should look like this -

```
<update-all-attributes>
       <document name="http:blah">
          <price>115.00 USD</price>
           <brand_qty>10A</brand_qty>
           <style_size>10A_newinstock</style_size>
       </document>
    </update-all-attributes>
```

This is the XSLT provided by another helpful coder -

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="document">
        <xsl:variable name="price" select="substring-before(normalize-space(price),' ')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="currency" select="substring-after(normalize-space(price),' ')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="difference" select="number($price) * .10"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            <discounted_price><xsl:value-of select="concat(format-number($price - $difference,'#,###.00'),' ',$currency)"/></discounted_price>
            <increased_price><xsl:value-of select="concat(format-number($price + $difference,'#,###.00'),' ',$currency)"/></increased_price>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the XSLT which I have tried and not been able to succeed-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="update-all-attributes">
        <xsl:for-each select="document">
            <size_availability>
                <xsl:call-template name="strip_spaces">
                    <xsl:with-param name="value" select="size_availability" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </size_availability>
            <size_InStk>
                <xsl:call-template name="strip_spaces">
                    <xsl:with-param name="value" select="size_InStk" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </size_InStk>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="strip_spaces">
        <xsl:param name="value" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not(contains($value, ' '))">
                <xsl:value-of select="$value" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:call-template name="strip_spaces">
                    <xsl:with-param name="value"
                        select="concat(substring-before($value, ' '), substring-after($value, ' '))" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please don't post XSLT you did not write as your own. I've seen your previous question, where you had literally nothing. Posting code from an answer to a previous question of yours and letting others make enhancements to it is two things: **A)** It's rude, because it shows that you value other peoples's time less than your own. **B)** It shows that you have no interest in learning from or understanding the answer you received, you just want someone to do your job. This question also proves that you didn't do any research *at all*.

Comment: Thanks. I am stuck. I am not posing the answer is mine.

Comment: Yes, you are. I see no sentence in your question that credits the author of the code. And "I am stuck" is not good enough, not by a long shot. Explain what research you did, what you have tried, link to documentation that failed to help you, *prove* that you did more than thinking about it for a few minutes before giving up.

Comment: Sorry corrected my mistake. I have put up my code which I have been trying. I referred W3 schools and WIKI XSLT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove spaces from the `brand_qty` and `style_size` elements, add another template to your stylesheet (the first one, not the one written by you):

```
<xsl:template match="brand_qty | style_size">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(., ' ', '')"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This is assuming you also want the added `discounted_price` and `increased_price` to appear in your output - unlike the output you have posted.

Comment: thanks. I tried it on the first XSL under <xsl:template match="document"> and it's not working.

Comment: does translate function belong to xslt 1.0? i hope the entire working xslt is in xslt 1.0 format, please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The translate() function can be used in XSLT 1.0.